# Generate near table for x number of neighbours using arcpy

Tags: python, arcpy, network

There are 3 likely scenerios that I am trying to capture near distances for:

1. An interchange subway station, which has 2 or more neighboring stations. That is, the station in question connects 2 or more major routes and has 2 or more neighboring stations.
2. A terminal subway station, which has only 1 neighboring station. This is the station at the end of the line.
3. An inline subway station, which has exactly 2 neighboring stations, one of either approach.

I am attempting to calculate a value one might call "average distance between neighboring stations"

The `arcpy.GenerateNearTable_analysis()` can handle two options: Distance to closest feature, and Distance between all features.

Does anyone have a clever method for solving for these scenarios? Note that each station is designated as "Interchange", "Terminal" or "Inline" in the attribute table under the field "StationType".

### Added:

Here is some psuedo code based on @whuber's suggestion in the comments. I don't have time to figure this out just yet, so if anyone wants to take a stab at it you'll be rewarded with a checkmark! ;)

I have taken a look at the [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/) library and it seems to work as I want it to.

Given the graph:

```
A —― B ―― C ―― D
     |
     E
```

as well as the nodes and links:

```
Nodes = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
Links = [("A", "B"), ("B", "C"), ("C", "D"), ("B", "E")]

def myFunction(node):
    identify the links that node belongs to
    count the number of links
    calculate the total link lengths
    divide the total link lengths by the number of links
    return someValue
```

Comment: I guess I can also mention that I am using ArcGIS 10.1 and I love the arcpy.da module (for its speed). I hope that we can use this.

Comment: FWIW this is purely a graph-theoretic problem with a standard solution: you seek the [neighborhood graph](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NeighborhoodGraph.html) of each vertex. It is available almost immediately as soon as you represent the network in a standard format, such as a [DCEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list) (or a generalization if the network in non-planar).  This suggests that some out-of-the-box Python solutions might be available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I beleive your problem, as @whuber, suggested would best be represented in an [Adjacency Matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AdjacencyMatrix.html).  That is, if you have the time and inclination to understand the theory behind it, rather than relying on a package to do the job for you.

For a given graph G, with vertices of {v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>,...,v<sub>n</sub>} where <sub>n</sub> is the number of vertices, you need to create a matrix of size M<sub>i,j</sub> where i = n and j = n.  Each vertex is then represented in the <sub>i</sub>th row by the number of paths found to adjacent verticies in the <sub>j</sub>th column.

Example below:

[image]

Given this mildly complex form of representing your relatively simple data, you will need to number your vertices in an arbitrary fashion, not representative of any logical order.

*NOTE: Assuming no station loops upon itself, a <sub>k</sub>th row will never have a value other than 0 in the <sub>k</sub>th column.  All definitions below assume this to be true*

*NOTE: Assuming there are no concurrent lines between the same station, all examples below assume that a cell value will only ever be 1 or 0.  The example above also assumes bidirectional travel is permitted.*

## Rules to identify station categories:

### 1. Terminal

A terminal would be identified by a <sub>k</sub>th row having a single column which does not have a value of 0, and which value is 1.  See vertices 1, 2, and 3 in example 1 above.

### 2. Junction

A junction would be identified by a <sub>k</sub>th row having more than two columns containing a value of 1. See vertex 4 in example 1 above, alternatively all vertices in example 3 above.

### 3. Inline

An inline station is signified by having exactly 2 columns in a <sub>k</sub>th row where the value is 1.  See all verticies in example 2 above.  (Ignore the fact that {v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>3</sub>} intersects {v<sub>2</sub>, v<sub>4</sub>}.)

Comment: Who are you and where did you come from! That was one of the best answers I've received in a long time. Thank you @Geoist.

Comment: @MichaelMarkieta Funny story, I **just** learned about this not 2 hours before I saw your post.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using [Shapely](https://github.com/sgillies/shapely). If you convert your arcpy points to shapely points, you can calculate the distance between individual points.

```
import arcpy
import shapely

arc_point1 = arcpy.Point(1,1)
arc_point2 = arcpy.Point(5,5)

shp_point1 = shapely.geometry.Point(arc_point1.X, arc_point1.Y)
shp_point2 = shapely.geometry.Point(arc_point2.X, arc_point2.Y)

distance = shp_point1.distance(shp_point2)
print "distance:", distance
```

Comment: I should mention that Shapely can only be used for features on a Cartesian plane, so this method won't work if your data are in geographic coordinates.

Comment: This answer suggests an ambiguity in how the question might be understood. I have read the question as indicating the *distances* are known; their computation does not appear to be the issue. What the OP seeks, I believe, is an algorithm for identifying a variable number of *immediate neighbors* of vertices along a network, to the end of then retrieving their distances and computing a statistical summary of them (such as an average).

Comment: @whuber  Oops! Agreed, I answered the question a bit too hastily.

Comment: @whuber is on the mark.

Comment: This wont work for me, but thanks!